# Multidimensional matrix of a class

Tags: c++, matrix

I am new in C++.

```
class ProjectionValue{
public:
    int angleLength;
    int detectorIndex_xLength;

    int detectorIndex_yLength;

    double ***matrix; 

    ProjectionValue(int angleLength, int detectorIndex_xLength, int detectorIndex_yLength);

    ~ProjectionValue();
};
```

I declared 3d matrix of ProjectionValue class (my class) in my main class.

```
ProjectionValue*** A_projection [10][10][5];

for(int x=0; x< A->Tomo->object3d->Nx; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y< A->Tomo->object3d->Ny; y++)
    {
        for(int z=0; z< A->Tomo->object3d->Nz; z++)
        {
            for( int kk=0; kk<11; kk++) 
            {
                for(int m=0; m < A->Tomo->detector->Nx; m++ )  
                {
                    for(int n=0; n < A->Tomo->detector->Ny; n++ )  
                    {
                        (**A_projection[x][y][z])->matrix[kk][m][n] = A->Tomo->ICD_projection(*A->Tomo->xraysource->Source,*A->Tomo->detector->GetCoordinates(m,n), initial_object, x, y, z);
                    }
                }

                A->Tomo->xraysource->RotateXRaySource(-5);
                A->Tomo->detector->RotateDetector(-5); 
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

I take"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Form_Solution.exe". It is here:

```
(**A_projection[x][y][z])->matrix[kk][m][n] = A->Tomo->ICD_projection(*A->Tomo->xraysource->Source,*A->Tomo->detector->GetCoordinates(m,n), initial_object, x, y, z);
```

What can I do for this problem, are there any problem in declaration of my 3d matrix of class? Is allocation memory of matrix necessary and how can I do it?

Comment: you haven't allocated memory for your matrix

Comment: how can I allocate this matrix?

Comment: Obligatory link to [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: @BoPersson I'd generally agree but a 3D matrix is a valid and viable construct - in any non-trivial code this will eventually lead to 3 stars

Comment: @icepack - No it doesn't. When you are at `double ***matrix` you have already lost it. In C++ I would start with `std::vector<Row> matrix` and then start to figure out what `Row` looks like.

Comment: @BoPersson and how do you pass a reference/pointer to the matrix to another entity? Yes, it might be better to use `vector` in C++ but that's another topic and 3-star programmer term stems from C.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ProjectionValue*** A_projection [10][10][5];
```

is not "a 3D array of `ProjectionValue` class". It is a 3D array of pointer to pointer to pointer to `ProjectionValue`. You probably want:

```
ProjectionValue A_projection [10][10][5];
```

unless you want the extra overhead of having to allocate (and de-allocate) all the pointers and objects yourself.

Comment: I did like yours, but I take error: ProjectionValue' : no appropriate default constructor available. how can I arrange my ProjectionValue constructor?

Comment: In order to allocate a static array of objects like that, your `ProjectionValue` class needs to have a default constructor (taking no arguments). If that is not feasible, you'll have to settle for the pointers to dynamically allocated memory route.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the way you wrote this personally.  I would just use an stl vector unless you want to write your own dynamically allocated array class.

```
using std::vector;

class Matrix3D
{
public:
Matrix3D(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned z)
{
   data.clear();
   data.resize(x);
   for(unsigned i=0;i<data.size();++i)
   {
      data[i].resize(y);
      for(unsigned j=0;j<data[i].size();++j)
      {
          data[i][j].resize(z);
      }
   }
}

vector< vector< vector< float > > > data;
};
```

I have not tried compiling this.